# How to make validations so only users with their unique ID can access certain parts of an app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, backbone.js

I made the classic todolist app for backbone(the walkthrough) http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html.  I set it up on rails(with a sqlite db).  My DB currently has a questions table and a users table.  Each Question ID belongs to a user.  How can I make only users that created the question have the ability to destroy the question?

If you can just give me a general explanation on how to do it, that would be a great.  I am not looking for specific code examples, I think I can manage that.  If you know of any good links or setups/examples on doing something like this I would greatly appreciate.  Thanks!

Comment: Check out `cancan` - https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally I do not like CanCan gem :)  (do not ask me why)

I do this in the controller

```
def destroy
  question = load_question
  render status: :not_found, nothing: true and return unless question.present?

  //destory your question here
end

private

  def load_question
    Question.where(id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id).first
  end
```

so only the current_user can delete the question, others will get a 404 (why not use 403? well you can, but I like to hide resources from the users so they don't know if something doesn't belong to them really exists in the system)

**EDIT**

usually you may want to hide the DELETE button in the UI as well. It's pretty easy to do in backbone as long as you have the current_user's object available in the front end. You can do it in your template: (or via a helper method in your question model)

```
// <% if (question.belongsTo(App.CurrentUser)) { %>
<% if (question.get('user_id') === App.CurrentUser.id) { %>
  //delete button
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the CanCan Gem.

It will help you create roles for your users and allow them to do certain actions for certain parts. It makes it very simple to pull them into the HTML erb as well.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan